# Concatenating distinct column values to a string

Tags: sql, concatenation, distinct

I want to select distinct combinations of columns to a string. I do not know how to do it in a query. The scenario is as under

```
c1   c2   c3
a     1    x
b     2    x
b     2    y
```

I want a resultset like

```
a:1:x
a:1:y
a:2:x
a:2:y
b:1:x
b:1:y
b:2:x
b:2:y
```

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Sample CREATE TABLE statement

```
create table #Test( c1 char(1), c2 char(1), c3 char(1) )
insert INTO #Test
SELECT
    'a', '1', 'x'
UNION ALL SELECT
    'b', '2', 'x'
UNION ALL SELECT
    'b', '2', 'y'
```

Combinations of all distinct column values

```
select 
    c1List.c1, c2List.c2, c3List.c3
from ( 
    select DISTINCT c1 from #Test ) c1List
CROSS JOIN (
    select DISTINCT c2 from #Test ) c2List
CROSS JOIN (
    select DISTINCT c3 from #Test ) c3List
```

String concatenations

```
select 
    c1List.c1 + ':' + c2List.c2 + ':' + c3List.c3
from ( 
    select DISTINCT c1 from #Test ) c1List
CROSS JOIN (
    select DISTINCT c2 from #Test ) c2List
CROSS JOIN (
    select DISTINCT c3 from #Test ) c3List
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat(c1,':',c2,':',c3) from 
(select distinct c3 from t) as t3, 
(select distinct c2 from t) as t2, 
(select distinct c1 from t) as t1
```

Answer (score -1):

`select concat(c1,':',c2,':',c3) from ...`